# Make something "have" or make something "to have"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, bare-infinitive

I am looking at a sentence in my thesis, and I am not sure about the usage of "make".

Should I say

> In addition, as a result of the xxx principal, the xxx product operation in (1) makes the received signals to have a non-linear structure.

or

> In addition, as a result of the xxx principal, the xxx product operation in (1) makes the received signals have a non-linear structure.

?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: ...or you could change the phrase after (1) to something like "produces [or _results in_] a non-linear structure in the received signals."

Comment: It's a good rephrase!

Answer (score 2):

You want the bare infinitive here:  "makes the received signals have."

The use of the **to-infinitive** was once more popular, and it survives in religious contexts where it has an archaic feel:

> he maketh me **to lie** down in green pastures

(It's hard to tell what's going on in the sentence because of the "xxx," but I'm willing to bet you want "xxx principle," and not "xxx principal.")

Comment: Quite right. I *make my son have a bath*. I do not *make my son **to** have a bath*.

Comment: But something could _cause_ the received signals to have a non-linear structure.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Bare infinitive  sounds better to me as well!

Answer (score 0):

I like Brian's proposal the best:

> In addition, as a result of the xxx **principle**, the xxx product operation in (1) **causes** the received signals to have a non-linear structure.

This language is more formal and better suited to a thesis.

Please note the spelling of *principle*.